# Transaction propagation between services in spring

Tags: spring, spring-data, spring-transactions

I have two services both are transactional with propagation REQUIRED. Service 2 is injected in service 1.Now method A in service 1 calls method B of service 2. Now I am invoking method A from client.My question is whether this invocation will

Create 1 transaction in which is created by Method A and method B will run in same transaction
Or
Create 2 transactions one for method A and other when A is calling B.

In my project services are transactional and for performing compound operations we have injected services inside other services.

Answer (score 0):

From [REQUIRED](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/annotation/Propagation.html#REQUIRED) java-doc:

> Support a current transaction, create a new one if none exists.

In your case - your variant is 1.

Note: You can control the creation of your transactions by enabling debug logging for `org.springframework.orm.jpa`.

More info from [official doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/data-access.html#tx-propagation).

Comment: Yes for REQUIRED attribute this behavior is correct.But here both services are transactional and hence spring will have proxy object of both service A and B .Now when Service A is calling method on B it is actually proxy of B is getting used to call the method in Target calls of B.So don't you think spring will apply advice again and will open transaction for B as well.Just like it did when client invokes method on service A.

Comment: @PravinMourya I don't 'think' - just read the [off. doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/data-access.html#tx-propagation) )) You can check it yourself by turning on debugging. Did you do this?

Comment: I will check... I was reading spring book in that they have mention this behavior (2 transactions) when DAO and service classes both have Transactional annotation. I thought same will apply to service methods as well.